# How can i 'run' this app in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service, tizen

I learn tizen app, i try to use sample app - hello accesory.

this is document. but it's so much simple and i can't understand how to run...

https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch/develop/samples/companion/hello-native

this project has 2 part, tizen app and android service.
but i use android service first.

i import(open) project in android studio and connect my phone. but i push 'run' or 'debug' button, this error occur.

```
Error running 'app'
Default Activity not found
```

i see a blog, he say 'use build - generate signed apk'. it work. i install to my phone through apk file.
but i can't know it really work. because i install tizen app and try connect, tizen-android connect isn't work....

i think android service is problem or tizen app is problem, but i can't any test on android.

i want how to know service is running now and how to debug in android studio.
lower is androidManifest.xml and source code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.helloaccessory.provider"
    android:versionCode="4"
    android:versionName="2.0.2" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.accessory.permission.ACCESSORY_FRAMEWORK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.WATCH_APP_TYPE.Companion" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.wmanager.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <service android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.helloaccessory.provider.ProviderService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.RegisterUponInstallReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.samsung.accessory.action.REGISTER_AGENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.ServiceConnectionIndicationBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.samsung.accessory.action.SERVICE_CONNECTION_REQUESTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="AccessoryServicesLocation"
            android:value="/res/xml/accessoryservices.xml" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="GearAppType"
            android:value="tpk" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

source code.

```
package com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.example.helloaccessory.provider;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

import com.samsung.android.sdk.SsdkUnsupportedException;
import com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.*;

public class ProviderService extends SAAgent {
    private static final String TAG = "HelloAccessory(P)";
    private static final Class<ServiceConnection> SASOCKET_CLASS = ServiceConnection.class;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private ServiceConnection mConnectionHandler = null;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    public ProviderService() {
        super(TAG, SASOCKET_CLASS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SA mAccessory = new SA();
        try {
            mAccessory.initialize(this);
        } catch (SsdkUnsupportedException e) {
            // try to handle SsdkUnsupportedException
            if (processUnsupportedException(e) == true) {
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            /*
             * Your application can not use Samsung Accessory SDK. Your application should work smoothly
             * without using this SDK, or you may want to notify user and close your application gracefully
             * (release resources, stop Service threads, close UI thread, etc.)
             */
            stopSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFindPeerAgentsResponse(SAPeerAgent[] peerAgents, int result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFindPeerAgentResponse : result =" + result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnectionRequested(SAPeerAgent peerAgent) {
        if (peerAgent != null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.ConnectionAcceptedMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            acceptServiceConnectionRequest(peerAgent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnectionResponse(SAPeerAgent peerAgent, SASocket socket, int result) {
        if (result == SAAgent.CONNECTION_SUCCESS) {
            if (socket != null) {
                mConnectionHandler = (ServiceConnection) socket;
            }
        } else if (result == SAAgent.CONNECTION_ALREADY_EXIST) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onServiceConnectionResponse, CONNECTION_ALREADY_EXIST");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAuthenticationResponse(SAPeerAgent peerAgent, SAAuthenticationToken authToken, int error) {
        /*
         * The authenticatePeerAgent(peerAgent) API may not be working properly depending on the firmware
         * version of accessory device. Please refer to another sample application for Security.
         */
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(SAPeerAgent peerAgent, String errorMessage, int errorCode) {
        super.onError(peerAgent, errorMessage, errorCode);
    }

    private boolean processUnsupportedException(SsdkUnsupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        int errType = e.getType();
        if (errType == SsdkUnsupportedException.VENDOR_NOT_SUPPORTED
                || errType == SsdkUnsupportedException.DEVICE_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            /*
             * Your application can not use Samsung Accessory SDK. You application should work smoothly
             * without using this SDK, or you may want to notify user and close your app gracefully (release
             * resources, stop Service threads, close UI thread, etc.)
             */
            stopSelf();
        } else if (errType == SsdkUnsupportedException.LIBRARY_NOT_INSTALLED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "You need to install Samsung Accessory SDK to use this application.");
        } else if (errType == SsdkUnsupportedException.LIBRARY_UPDATE_IS_REQUIRED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "You need to update Samsung Accessory SDK to use this application.");
        } else if (errType == SsdkUnsupportedException.LIBRARY_UPDATE_IS_RECOMMENDED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "We recommend that you update your Samsung Accessory SDK before using this application.");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public ProviderService getService() {
            return ProviderService.this;
        }
    }

    public class ServiceConnection extends SASocket {
        public ServiceConnection() {
            super(ServiceConnection.class.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int channelId, String errorMessage, int errorCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(int channelId, byte[] data) {
            if (mConnectionHandler == null) {
                return;
            }
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd aa hh:mm:ss.SSS");
            String timeStr = " " + dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
            String strToUpdateUI = new String(data);
            final String message = strToUpdateUI.concat(timeStr);
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mConnectionHandler.send(getServiceChannelId(0), message.getBytes());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onServiceConnectionLost(int reason) {
            mConnectionHandler = null;
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), R.string.ConnectionTerminateddMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error shows there's no Default Activity

Comment: Don't trust Samsung developers. They have no idea how to create samples of their own sh* hm "very nice" software. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your app project don't have activity declared,
You need to have activity with this attribute

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Example:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

You need to declare launch activity for avoid the

> Default Activity not found